# Plot multiple datasets in one plot using ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three different datasets, i.e. data1, data2, and data3. I want to plot them in one figure. Here is my code:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_classic())

data1 <- expand.grid(
  lambda_c = seq(0.5, 2, 0.1),
  K = seq(50, 100)
) %>%
  mutate(
    clado = lambda_c * exp(-20 /K)
  )

data2 <- expand.grid(
  mu = seq(0.1, 0.8, 0.1),
  K = seq(50, 100)
) %>% mutate(
  ext = mu - 0.001 * K
)

data3 <- expand.grid(
  gamma0 = seq(0.05, 0.15, 0.025),
  K = seq(50, 100)
) %>% mutate(
  immig = gamma0 * exp(-20 / K)
)

data1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = K, y = clado, alpha = lambda_c)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.1, 1.0)) 
  
data2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=K, y=ext, alpha = mu)) +
  geom_point(color = "yellow") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.1, 1.0)) 

data3 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=K, y=immig, alpha = gamma0)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.1, 1.0))
```

Can someone help me out of this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try looking at `ggpubr::ggarrange`, `cowplot::grid`, `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, or the `patchwork` package.